# How to add solution without Windows Authentication to SharePoint DB?

Tags: sharepoint

Is there any way to run stsadm -o addsolution using a SQL Authentication account instead of the windows domain account? My SharePoint hosting provider has the content database in a different domain than my WFE and they are not trusted. I am unable to install a SharePoint solution pacakge using stsadm because my windows domain account does not have permission in the config database. I do have a SQL authentication account, but can't find a way to use it using the stsadm command.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to access the content database server if you are deploying a solution package to the WFE server? You need to contact your provider's support for permissions or have them deploy it for you...

Comment: Sorry, I meant the sharepoint config database, not the content database. I will update my question. I am trying to add the solution, not even deploy it yet. I am trying to get my provider to help, but they keep telling me it should work as is. I have been going back an forth with them for a few months now and am looking for some more ideas. Thanks.

Comment: What error message are you getting? You need to post more details on the setup. Did you try deploying it via Central Admin?